# Dissect the pixel-heads

Tags: geometry, dissection

Here are two figures, each composed of 54 pixels.  Cut each figure into **six [nonominoes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonomino)** having the same shape and size.

- Both figures use the same nonomino
- The nonominoes could be rotated, reflected, or both
- The four colors (blue, green, pink, gray) are for artistic effect only.  These colors have no relationship to the solution.

[image: Pixel-heads]

Comment: Those nonominoes puzzles are great! Love them.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Found it!

> [image]

Very nice! I wasted 30min until I've realized I mis-drew my black & white copy with only 53 squares! :c)

---

**Edit:** 
As requested, and for the purpose of this site (*teaching* how to build/solve puzzles) I'm adding how I found the solution to this puzzle. 
General considerations:

> - Mostly by **trial & error**. I'm using a graphic program with layers/objects (i.e. Powerpoint) such that I can easily modify & clone tiles while trying fitting together the puzzle.
> - The **tile-size** of the nonominoes **is known** if all are of same size, the total field size is known, and the number of nomoninoes is known.
> - Then I start with one (in this case close to a hole) and copy/tilt it to see if they fit. Rule-out conditions are:
>
>   - two noominoes overlap
>   - isolated 'holes' are created
> - From there, it's a **process of reduction**, guided by intuition. (i.e. usually good puzzles have rather 'complicated' nonomino-shapes. So I try those first.)
> - Sometimes it helps to do the process with a *partial* nonomino (i.e. of smaller size) first. This rules out whole sets of shapes. (If you have a problem with a 5-sized shape, **no** bigger shape will work out.)

As for this *particular* puzzle:

> - The **tile-size** of the nonominoes **is known** to be 9, because we have to fit 6 tiles into 54 fields, hence: 6 x **9** = 54. 
>  In the particular puzzle, it was soon clear that nonominoes had to partly wrap *around* a one-square hole. Few tries showed that it had to be a "5-tiles around hole" solution. 
>  - So I made this 5-sized nonomino and copied it 6 times, arranging it around the head-holes. 
>  - Then I successively added 1 square (i.e. made all 6-sized, 7-sized...). One could immediately see, what fits, and what wouldn't. As always: You must not create overlaps and you must not create isolated holes.
>  - I actually only solved the left head. It was then immediately visible, that the right one has just a mirror in it's left half.

Comment: Is there any special way to solve things like this? I had no idea how to even start thinking.

Comment: @Quark: I've edited in some guidelines and my path to the solution. Thanks for suggesting it. This site **is about *teaching***, so such an edit is a very good idea indeed.