# A Masterpiece: A mirror or an ABC?

Tags: wordplay, enigmatic-puzzle

I have worked on this masterpiece  for *soooo* long, hope you all like it!

---

**The PUZZLE**

> A is for the adventurous who approached the door
>   B bragged his brilliant bronze when there isn't even one
>   C is the Chinese classifier living with a chimpanzee 
>   D is the detective against the diamond maze
>   E stands for excellent with no questions, only explanations
>   F is the one who finds nothing in "fishy"
>   G goes round and round on the ground
>   H can hop from here to there, if only he himself is here
>   I has the illustration to replace the il-favoured nails
>   J's done a puzzle (again) in "5,0,1"
>   K is a kutie disguised in a quart
>   L looks into life with layers of pixels
>   M is for the master who managed to find the modest
>   N is nothing naughty with the apple-beaten curious dog  
>   O likes to play with Optimal Prime
>   P plays with the periodic table with a poor professor
>   Q keeps the quack away with qi queer apples
>   R renders riddles with rations of word
>   S, stealthy, should show off his small art with score 0
>   T finds a trench in a thread
>   U would be unsatisfied if he lived in an unitone universe
>   V is for the virtuoso in making veiled veiled clues
>   W would vision two countries in one
>   X is a xpectrum xeen from above
>   Z knows well sZYX, in Greek as well, itz here, you zee?

---

Disclaimer

> Sorry in advance if you feel in anyway offended, and please feel free to tell me in the comments!

---

Partial answers are welcomed

---

**Criteria:**

The accepted answer should also provide the links (if you know what I mean) **and**

> Y is Y missing?

---

**Sorry**

As mentioned by @GarethMcCaughan♦:

> There is no specific rule in which of the list I chose... 
> I was going to follow a rule, but that would be too difficult for my puzzle making...
> Therefore, some are easy, some are hard...
> Enjoy!

Edit:

> There's a threshold to make our lives easier, and it can loosely be called a 'rule', or a limit at least

---

**HINTS:**

About me:

> I am lazy. I go through the user list in PSE. I look for one starting with the letter required, then try to make a riddle out of him/ her.

D: (couldn't believe this needs a hint)

> twisted deceitful diamond

I:

> [image: i hint]

N:

> Such a cute racoon!!!

S:

> I **steal** stuff from **far** away...

T:

> Where can we find a hole in a thing with a hole in it?

U:

> pɪƐ

V:

> "Voila! There it is!"
>  What can you **hear**?

V Hint 2:

> [image]

W:

> 'll

Overall:

> Dear senpais of PSE: reflect on your life! What have you contributed in PSE?

---

**HERE IS A RECORD OF YOUR PROGRESS:**

> [image]

Comment: Rot13(Vf gung fhccbfrq gb or Bcgvz**hf** Cevzr?) - _line 15_

Comment: No it is fine as it is

Comment: Y is missing :o

Comment: Y is Y missing anyway, @OmegaKrypton?

Comment: no user with first letter y and rep >1000 @KradCigol

Comment: Oh, thanks! It appears my answer was wrong by 1000 reputation.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here is a more complete solution with the contributions from me, Gareth McCaughan, Bass, jafe, TwoBitOperation, QuantumTwinkie, Krad Cigol, El-Guest and the OP, Omega Krypton

A (found by Gareth McCaughan)

> Alconja - [You have prepared. You are determined. You approach the door](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/31557/you-have-prepared-you-are-determined-you-approach-the-door)

B

> Bass [How Many Policemen?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/59892/how-many-policemen)

C

> Chowzen [Do I Work with an Orangutan?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/66761/do-i-work-with-an-orangutan)

D (found originally by Gareth McCaughan, but also subsequently by QuantumTwinkie and Krad Cigol)

> Deusovi - [Deusovi Honeypot](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/58255/deusovi-honeypot)

E

> [El-Guest](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/50778/el-guest), a user who has accumulated all their points from answers and not asked a single question.

F

> f'' - this [answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/19830/18422) - was on the right track but they did not find the appropriate letter in "FISHY DISH" to solve the clue.

G (found by QuantumTwinkie)

> Glorfindel - [A walk of 3000 meters, but one foot has moved more, how so?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/65001/a-walk-of-3000-meters-but-one-foot-has-moved-more-how-so/65004#65004)

H

> hexomino https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/68003/18422

I (revealed by Omega Krypton)

> itriedacrab - [Sometimes I'm ugly, sometimes I'm art. What am I?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/10907/sometimes-im-ugly-sometimes-im-art-what-am-i/10922#10922)

J (link found by jafe)

> jafe - [Grandpa and numbers: Another Grandpa Mystery](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/70518/grandpa-and-numbers-another-grandpa-mystery/70519#70519)

K

> kayzeroshort https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/35973/18422

L

> Len [Dissect the pixel-heads](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/7762/dissect-the-pixel-heads/7778)

M (found by Bass)

> M Oehm - https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/42127/18422

N

> NudgeNudge with [this](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/78029/18422) - "apple-beaten curious dog" has all its words in alphabetical order.

O

> Oray [4 Gridded Prime Numbers](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/42343/4-gridded-prime-numbers/42372)

P (found by Gareth McCaughan)

> PerpetualJ - [An Odd New Technology](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/72319/an-odd-new-technology)

Q

> QuantumTwinkie - https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/63998/18422

R (found by Gareth McCaughan)

> Riley - [My prefix is food, my suffix is rude](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/62349/my-prefix-is-food-my-suffix-is-rude)

S

> Sleafar - https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/23752/18422

T (found by TwoBitOperation)

> TwoBitOperation - [What is designed to go into holes and always has a hole in it?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/65161/what-is-designed-to-go-into-holes-and-always-has-a-hole-in-it/65163#65163)

U

> user477343  - [I am described by temperature, and never by looks. I might be found in your camera, as well as children's books](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/67883/i-am-described-by-temperature-and-never-by-looks-i-might-be-found-in-your-came)

V (found by El-Guest)

> Volatility - [Cryptic Poem: a study in what?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/25055/cryptic-poem-a-study-in-what)

W (found by Krad Cigol)

> Will - [Who won the world cup quarter-finals?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/31769/who-won-the-world-cup-quarter-finals/31770#31770)

X (found by QuantumTwinkie)

> xnor - [Merlin and Hermes: Mysterious Lines](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/6165/merlin-and-hermes-mysterious-lines/6166#6166)

Z (found by QuantumTwinkie)

> zeethreepio - [What is missing from this sequence of words?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/72203/what-is-missing-from-this-sequence-of-words/72217#72217)

Comment: Might match [mysterious Mister M](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/42127/36023)?

Comment: Ah, yes, I was thinking of them but couldn't fit the clue.

Comment: 501 is DI... maybe J refers to [this](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/50378/building-a-pyramid-from-di-spheres)?

Comment: @OmegaKrypton Aaaa maybe it's [this](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/70519/41973)...?

Comment: @OmegaKrypton I've not come back to it in a week or so, searching through to find the answers is proving difficult. I've updated with jafe's suggestion and one more of my own.

Comment: @OmegaKrypton Found 'U' I think.

Comment: giving this bounty for the one who got the most... well done! i is itriedacrab : https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/10907/sometimes-im-ugly-sometimes-im-art-what-am-i/10922#10922

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan Sorry, I didn’t realize you had already found Deusovi.

Answer (score 15):

I don't like making an answer as partial as this one, but OP specifically said partials are welcome and I might as well get the ball rolling.

I'm fairly sure that

> we are looking for PSE posters and some of their puzzles. (This explains the otherwise puzzling remark about offending people.)

Specifically,

A is for the adventurous who approached the door

> Alconja: [You have prepared. You are determined. You approach the door](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/31557/you-have-prepared-you-are-determined-you-approach-the-door)

P plays with the periodic table with a poor professor

> PerpetualJ: [An Odd New Technology](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/72319/an-odd-new-technology)

R renders riddles with rations of word

> Riley: [My prefix is food, my suffix is rude](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/62349/my-prefix-is-food-my-suffix-is-rude) (and of course the deluge of derived decompositions it led to)

Stealthy S should show off his small art with score 0

> Possibly The Great "S"-caper with [Mortin Myes' is at it again! 'HOW TO READ.'](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/56974/mortin-myes-is-at-it-again-how-to-read) or stacksfiller with [A puzzle in 140 characters](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/54165/a-puzzle-in-140-characters) and its double-sized sequel -- but I'm not sure why "with score 0" for either, so I may be missing something.

But

> identifying *all* of these seems like a thankless task; I suspect I am missing some key point about exactly *which* users and *which* puzzles we are looking for. We definitely aren't looking for the highest-rated puzzle by a user with each starting letter (else Roland would have beaten out Riley), nor the highest-rated puzzle by each selected user (else Alconja would be represented by a different one), nor the most recent puzzle by each selected user (else Riley would be represented by a different one), nor the top-rated usre with each starting letter (else Rand would have beaten out Riley).

It's possible that

> D is actually [Deusovi Honeypot](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/58255/deusovi-honeypot) which is *about* Deusovi but posted by someone else, in which case my summary of what's going on above is a bit inexact. If that sort of thing is allowed then of course the task of identifying everyone and everything is even larger. In a similar vein, E seems like it might be about someone who posts only answers but no questions -- but right now the only notable PSE user I can think of who does that is, er, me, and none of my names begins with E.

Comment: i'm an answerer and not an inquisitor (thus far), though I lack notability and the letter E!

Comment: 3/4 correct for both answer and explanation! +1

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan are you not trying to do this anymore? :(

Comment: I didn’t think you were the _only_ one to not ask any questions, Gareth.... ;)

Comment: @El-Guest wow! *[scrolling through ancient questions of my own...]*

Answer (score 7):

The very most partial, but I think **T** might be:

> Myself (**T**woBitOperation). Specifically, this answer to:
>  [What is designed to go into holes and always has a hole in it?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/65161/what-is-designed-to-go-into-holes-and-always-has-a-hole-in-it/65163#65163)

Which matches both given clues:
- finds a trench in a thread
- where can we find a hole in a thing with a hole in it?

Comment: correct, nice job! @TwoBitOperation

Comment: added new hints please check ;)

Comment: Added a lot of hints, please check!

Answer (score 6):

Edit:
D seems to be

> Deusovi, specifically, [this puzzle.](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/58255/deusovi-honeypot).
> Diamond, because he is a moderator, and maze due to this puzzle.

N might be

> This user, [NL628](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/43256/nl628), though I’m not sure which puzzle yet.

W is

> Will, to be specific, [this answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/31769/who-won-the-world-cup-quarter-finals/31770#31770)- each country actually stood for two.

Even more partial than @TwoBitOperation, but I think Y is missing because

> There are no puzzling.stackexchange users beginning with *Y* above 2000 reputation.

Comment: Added a lot of hints, please check!

Comment: so far: d and w correct, n incorrect. keep it up!

Answer (score 5):

Partial

D

> [Deusovi](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/11876/deusovi),because he has a diamond by his name? Not sure of the puzzle though.

G

> [Glorfindel](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/11110/glorfindel), he answers a puzzle were the answer had to do with going a round a running track. [A walk of 3000 meters, but one foot has moved more, how so?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/65001/a-walk-of-3000-meters-but-one-foot-has-moved-more-how-so/65004#65004)

I?

> [Ian MacDonald](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/10399/ian-macdonald), and possibly this post? [What famous line does this Linux command line represent?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/11025/what-famous-line-does-this-linux-command-line-represent/11028#11028)

X

> [Xnor](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/4551/xnor), and he answered a question were he had to say what the word was from the top view. [Merlin and Hermes: Mysterious Lines](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/6165/merlin-and-hermes-mysterious-lines/6166#6166).

Z

> [Zeethreepio](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/50321/zeethreepio) and he answered this puzzle about Greek letters. [What is missing from this sequence of words?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/72203/what-is-missing-from-this-sequence-of-words/72217#72217).

Comment: correct so far for all three of them! well done!

Comment: i is wrong, keep it up!

Answer (score 4):

If V is still missing, it could be for

> Volatility, and [this puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/25055/50778), one of many cryptics and enigmatic puzzles which seem to be their favourites.

A bigger stretch, but I could be for

> Ivo Beckers, specifically with the diagram/illustration in [this answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/45682/50778).

Comment: the first one is correct, well done!

Comment: Figured that the second one wouldn’t be, thanks though @OmegaKrypton!