# A Sequel: A Test or an ABC?

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, rhyme, knowledge, story

A Sequel for [A Masterpiece: A mirror or an ABC?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/78451/a-masterpiece-a-mirror-or-an-abc/) , thanks for all your support for that puzzle, and hope you like this!

> In a science quiz you scratched your head,
>
> For it was a puzzle nowhere it led.
>
> Memories floated: your father tucking you to bed,
>
> Where bit by bit with you knowledge he'd fed.
>
> And this is the science ABC,
>
> With this shall no challenge difficult be.
>
> With A you check how much the loop's worth currently
>
> With B how bright you see
>
> c how the ray passes steadfastly
>
> And D, sink or float, that's the key!
>
> Sir e! Most negative, with challenges, toils and gore.
>
> Resisted, yet charging, journey he not abhors.
>
> For the F he longed for
>
> Though grounded by g to core
>
> For endless h's he his energy tore,
>
> If running for dreamy i, what's all that for?
>
> Hasn't he measured with J his losses,
>
> And K his heat gained for being crossed?
>
> The l of the journey he measured,
>
> By m and m he ventured,
>
> But "Out!" went Black, and all ended for sure.
>
> N here we go, up in the air,
>
> where O also got his share.
>
> But P was large up in the atmosphere,
>
> So be rational like Q, get back down here.
>
> r! My radiation are far too small,
>
> My life in half, in s's, that's all.
>
> And there's never enough t before I fall.
>
> Oh yeah, I am U, that's how I'm called,
>
> Though I possess the V potentially,
>
> I shall not shine as bright as W.
>
> x cuse me sir, I'm of no match,
>
> To y, who stood straight like a match!
>
> But the final victor would be z up high,
>
> Who both x and y couldn't fetch but sigh!
>
> Now who goes "Oooo!"
>
> And knows what to do?

Comment: is this question still active?

Comment: shall we start a bounty?

Comment: May I also post my answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Partial answer**

On the face of it, this is just

> looking for a sequence of scientific words beginning with letters A to Z. (Or, in some cases, those letters used as symbols.)

Specifically:

> A(mpere); B?; c, the speed of light; D(ensity); e(lectron); F might be farad (cf. "charging" in previous line) or force (cf. gravity in next line)? g(ravity) or gravitational acceleration at earth's surface; h(ours)???; i (*imaginary* ~= *dreamy*???); J(oule); K(elvin); l(ength); m(etre); N(itrogen); O(xygen); P(pressure); Q (field of rational numbers); r?; s(econd); t(ime); U?; V(oltage) or just V indicating any potential; W (tungsten in an incandescent bulb? or just watts???); x,y,z (coordinates)

But I suspect I'm missing something because

> it isn't obvious to me that all of these are particularly unique, and the ending of the question seems to suggest that we're supposed to spot some further thing once we've found the individual words.

Also,

> I haven't found anything plausible for B.

Comment: Wonder if in this case rot13(O nf va O-svryq/Zntargvp svryq. Va guvf pnfr vg vapernfrf jvgu gur pheerag naq fb n ohyof oevtugarff jbhyq vapernfr. e pbhyq or enqvhf/qvfgnapr qhr gb vairefr fdhner ynj.) hope this helps

Comment: _Maybe_, but it seems a bit tenuous. But most of the question seems a bit tenuous and, again, I think I'm probably missing something.

Comment: Long shot for "B" - something to do with Rot13(Avryf Obue)?

Comment: Also conceivable but tenuous :-).

Comment: 1st spoiler: correct! 2nd: f latter g former v latter 3rd u're thinking too much, my friend... 4th: there is something ;)

Comment: B is the scientific symbol for luminence (or how bright a light is), and r could simply be the radius? The names of the coordinates are: x = abscissa, y = ordinate, z = altitude

Comment: That would be all very well, except that B is not the scientific symbol for luminance. Luminance is generally denoted by L, and the unit of luminance is cd/m^2 which doesn't have a B anywhere in it. See e.g. the table at the end of [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luminance).

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan Huh, that's funny. I looked at [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_letters_used_in_mathematics_and_science) and it lists "luminance" under "B"... But the [actual page about Luminance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luminance) doesn't list B as any official symbol.

Comment: sorry for my super late tick... well done!

Answer (score 1):

Trying my best: (Creds to Gareth McCaughan)

> A: Ampere
>  B: Brightness
>  C: ***c*** (speed of light)
>  D: Density
>  E: Electron
>  F: Flow
>  G: Gravity
>  H: Hole
>  I: Ionization
>  J: Joule
>  K: Kelvin
>  L: Length
>  M: Miles
>  N: Nitrogen
>  O: Oxygen
>  P: Pressure
>  Q: ***q*** (positive integer denominator)
>  R: Roentgen
>  S: ?
>  T: Time
>  U: U (a name)
>  V: Voltage
>  W: Watt
>  X: length
>  Y: Width
>  Z: Height

Comment: Hi there, it's fine to answer a question (even with a tick) whenever you feel that you have a better answer. But later, please put spoiler tag and also don't "spam" ><