# Piece de Resistance - Introduction & Ace and A's

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay

### OP's Words

<sub>This puzzle is part of the "Piece de Resistance" series. Read the following section for the story
[**Ace**](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/86871/piece-de-resistance-introduction-ace-and-as) [Two](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/86924/piece-de-resistance-two-boxes-two-boxes-of-letters) [Three](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/86959/piece-de-resistance-three-troublesome-toshes) [Four](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/87049/piece-de-resistance-four-dots-in-a-line) [Five](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/87107/piece-de-resistance-five-flowers-with-one-missing) ...</sub>

Hey guys (and gals), I have worked on this for weeks, took me even more effort than "[A Masterpiece: A mirror or an ABC?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/78451/a-masterpiece-a-mirror-or-an-abc)". Hope y'all like it, and don't forget to press the upward button if you like it and/or appreciate my effort :D

### Prologue

On Sunday night, you went to the bar to chill with your friend. After chatting for a while, your friend produced a deck of cards from his pocket.

> "Here, happy birthday, mate! Bye for now!"

And then, without a word, he left.

You flipped through the cards, but they aren't the kind of playing cards you normally see. On the top-right corner of each of the cards are labels, from A through K. Strange though, there is no suit. You soon realised there is only one suit of 13 cards here.

### Ace - and A's

You observed the Ace card in detail. It has a silver glossy surface. You tried rubbing a coin against the surface, and you realised there was another layer under the silver surface. The surface underneath was more like a typical playing card, with a white shiny facade. The black text on it says:

> $\mathfrak{\text{Ace, I may be to the ear, without one letter.}}$
>   $\mathfrak{\text{A's, I may be to the eye, without two letters.}}$
>   $\mathfrak{\text{See? Three letters gone!}}$
>   $\mathfrak{\text{I am a victim.}}$

Comment: "under the siver surface" - a typo?

Comment: $\mathfrak{Nice  \ use  \ of }$ ~ mathfrak

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> *Case* sounds like *ace* when you remove one letter (the first), looks like *a's* when you remove two letters (the first and last), is *c* (sounds like *see*) when you remove three letters (the last three), and is a victim of (falls to) arguments in a [proof by cases](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/proof_by_cases). I don't, however, see a connection to the title ("Piece de Resistance - Introduction").

Comment: Gah, formatting cost me!

Comment: PS I expect the title will prove to be the first in a complex series of puzzles... :) +1 by the way

Comment: @Stiv I like your explanation for the “I am a victim” line much better, though — regardless of time submitted.

Answer (score 9):

Is the answer:

> CASE

*Ace, I may be to the ear, without one letter*

> Remove the C - the remainder 'ASE' sounds like 'Ace'.

*A's, I may be to the eye, without two letters*

> Remove the E as well to get 'AS'.

*See? Three letters gone!*

> Instead remove ASE and you are left with 'C', which sounds like 'see'.

*I am a victim.*

> 'Case' in the police sense of the word - a case to solve...