# What is a Swear Word™?

Tags: pattern, word-property

<sub>*In the spirit of the What is a [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aword+is%3Aquestion)/[Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aphrase+is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463), a special brand of [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aphrase+is%3Aquestion+user%3A463) and [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aword+is%3Aquestion+user%3A463) puzzles.
Template taken from Rubio.*</sub>

---

[A break from the [Piece de Resistance](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/86871/piece-de-resistance-introduction-ace-and-as/) series, another one of the series will be posted hopefully within one day.]

Well, this question does not ment to inspire your thinking, but rather an enticement to your recollections in the childhood, given the title is a FAQ, especially when you ask "Is *** a swear word?" to your parents. [humor](/questions/tagged/humor) can be added if you want. Have fun :-)

If a word conforms to a special rule, I call it a ***Swear Word™***.
Use the following examples below to find the rule.

| Swear Words™ | Not Swear Words™ |
| --- | --- |
| pens | pencils |
| crap | excrement |
| swear | oath |
| hell | netherworld |
| bloody | sickly |
| seamen | sailors |
| bad | wicked |
| good | beneficial |
| gender | sex |
| ardour | lust |
| focus | fetus |
| love | passion |
| hungry | Hungary |
| pure | purity |

Here is a csv version:

```
Swear Words™, Not Swear Words™
pens, pencils
crap, excrement
swear, oath
hell, netherworld
bloody, sickly
seamen, sailors
bad, wicked
good, beneficial
gender, sex
ardour, lust
focus, fetus
love, passion
hungry, Hungary
pure, purity
```

Well, remember to explain the title as well! Have fun!

Hints:

<sub>usefulness level 1</sub>

> The relation required has nothing to do with the meanings of the words

Comment: For those who consider the cr*p to vulgar, carp would also work, Have fun ;-)

Comment: rot13(V pna'g uryc guvaxvat gung craf naq frnzra eryngr (ivn bar yrggre nqqvgvba be erzbiny) gb cravf naq frzra...)

Comment: I'm sure that's one reason why those particular words were chosen :-). (But I bet it has nothing to do with the rule.)

Comment: **This** comment is for hint request. pls upvote this comment if you need a hint. I will use this as a reference for when i should give a hint to you all. thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Not enough rep to comment, so I'll leave my comments here.

Is it a coincidence that:

> All Swear Words™ can be written in cursive without lifting your pen, whereas all Not Swear Words™ (except gory) cannot be written this way? i.e. Not Swear Words™ contains letters such as "i, x, t, H", which all require a second stroke to complete? Like I said, this pattern holds for all words except for "gory".

Comment: oops... my fault... nicely done!

Comment: @OmegaKrypton if this is the correct answer, then perhaps a checkmark?  If it is not, that would be worth knowing.

Comment: and the title is due to CURSE...ive

Comment: Ohh, I was thinking it was something along the lines of swear==promise --> "Cross my heart..." --> cross.